# How do I negate a value in an Excel calculated field for a pivot table?

Tags: excel

I've got a pivot table that has a sum of numbers aggregated per month per category. My data table looks like this:

```
Date       | Description | Amount | Transaction Type | Category    | Account Name   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
12/16/2017 | Dinner      | 150.00 | debit            | Restaurants | CC
12/16/2017 | Return      | 80.00  | credit           | Restaurants | Cash
```

For the calculated field's formula, I've tried `=IF('Transaction Type'="credit", -1*Amount, Amount)` but it's just giving me the same `sum` of `Amount`. For this sum, I'd expect it to be `70.00 (150 - 80)`. Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You are after adding a `calculated item` rather than a `calculated field` as you are relying on the value of the field `"Transaction Type"` to determine the calculation result. See reference [here](http://www.contextures.com/excelpivottablecalculateditem.htm)

I assumed (oops) you meant credit - debit but, if not, simply swop the items around in the formula.

With your initial pivottable set up

[image: Initial pivottable]

With either Debit or Credit in the column headers of the pivot selected goto
`Fields, Items, & Sets` in the `Analyze` tab and selected `Calculated Item`
then add the following:

Name: `Net`

Formula:  `=' credit           '-' debit            '`

[image: Calculated item]

Example layout final:

[image: Final layout]

As noted in the link:

You will:

> NOT be able to move the field to the Report Filters area
>
> NOT be able to add multiple copies of a field to the Values area.
>
> Extra items might be created in the pivot tables, such as cities
>   appearing in all regions, with zero values.

Comment: @pnuts I noticed that they stated +70 but i assumed they actually mean to debit from the credit. Have i got this wrong? I will simply swop the items in the formula if so?